# AS3 - Button titles

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I would like to show a title if the mouse cursor gets on a button. (Similar to HTML's *title tag*)
I've more than 40 buttons on stage. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.
Uli

Comment: Sorry, but can you be more specific please, where do you want the 'title' to appear? Above the button that you're hovering over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as I'm aware there is no property for simpleButton to specify a tool-tip/title text when the mouse hovers over. You'd have to do it manually.

One tutorial (simpler and more straight forward than some of the others) can be found here: http://www.flashuser.net/flash-tricks/tips-tricks-8-actionscript-30-easy-made-tooltip.html

You would then apply it to all 40 of your buttons via ActionScript using a loop.

Alternatively you can add a mouse over event to all of your buttons and just call a function that would update a TextField's text somewhere on the stage.

Answer (score -1):

hey u can download from here i have make it for you

http://www.4shared.com/zip/0OLNedGF/btn.html